# How can I change color of editable text in FXForms?

Tags: ios, objective-c, fxforms

How can I change color of editable text in [FXForms](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXForms)? I've tried `@"textLabel.color"` and `@"detailTextLabel.color"` but it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: what is an FX form ? How you are using it in your view controller ?

Comment: you can simply change the tint color of the textfield!!!

Comment: The arrow-marked element is not a label, it's a text field. You will probably need a different key. `@"textField.textColor"`?

Comment: @rokjarc Yes, you are right. It worked. Please write an answer and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to use appropriate keyPath: in your case it should be

```
@{@"textField.textColor": [UIColor redColor]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line in the `FXForms.m` file

Under `FXFormTextFieldCell` implementation:

in `- (void)setUp` method:

Or you can also override the setup method from your view controller

```
self.textField.textColor = [UIColor yourColor];//[UIColor colorWithRed:0.275f green:0.376f blue:0.522f alpha:1.000f];
```

Comment: FXforms can also be added to project by Cocoapods (for example). It's not a good idea to directly modify the library source - it defies the purpose of using dependency management.

Comment: Oh, i misunderstood that he should modify the source file. Sorry about that. Yes, overriding setup (in sublass) is also a valid approach.